# Authenticating SSL in a Windows Proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, iphone

I need to inspect some traffic from my iPhone to debug an application, which is going and coming from an https address.

Since I don't have a Mac at the moment, I tried with Paros proxy, which I had used before. It's working fine with http connections, but whenever I try to open a website with SSL encryption in Mobile Safari it says that the certificate is not trusted. I can "Continue" and it would work, but not on Applications.

How can I set up a trusted certificate with Paros and the iPhone?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

**UPDATE:**
I'm going to try and create my own SSL certificate for testing with [Windows' MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548309.aspx)

**UPDATE 2:**
For some reason I could get Windows SDK to install, so I haven't tried this yet...

**UPDATE 3:** Now trying with OWASP ZAP, in case someone has more experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)?

> The Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) is an easy to use integrated penetration testing tool for finding vulnerabilities in web applications.
>   It is designed to be used by people with a wide range of security experience and as such is ideal for developers and functional testers who are new to penetration testing.
>   ZAP provides automated scanners as well as a set of tools that allow you to find security vulnerabilities manually.

Its a fork of Paros which is being actively developed (unlike Paros;)
I havnt tried proxying traffic from an iPhone, but we have rewritten the SSL handling, so it may work.

Generate a root CA cert for ZAP and then import it into your iPhone.

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: I have generated a certificate using ZAP, in the Dynamic SSL Certificates tab, and imported it to the iPhone. Also installed it on my computer. But whenever I browse an https address it shows an error message saying it's not trusted (On the iPhone) Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm afraid I dont have an iPhone so I cant try this out myself. But I've asked on our dev list: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/zaproxy-develop/SxGsm3phKWw/discussion and will update this thread if anyone has any good suggestions.

Comment: When you imported it into your iPhone, did you have the option to install it as a trusted CA? I've just found this article, which is a bit old, but may help importing Root certs: http://searchconsumerization.techtarget.com/tutorial/Configure-CA-certificates-for-iPhone-and-Exchange-Server-2007